# Process.Start removing text from textboxes on other forms

Tags: vb.net-2010, process.start

I have a program that stores client information, as the program has evolved I have moved some data over to two other forms (a demographics form and a treatment plan form).  On the main page I have a few pictureboxes along the top that you can click on that `process.starts` a web link to view information online (It's a formatted Google Search link that shows things like the clients weather depending on their county of residence, or the sheriffs office number based on the county+state they live in).

The issue I'm having is that it unloads all the data in demographics and treatment plan, but not on the main form (I have all fields being loaded from a txt into a public list then distributed out to the associated fields and forms on the main form when the client is selected from a dropdown, and the demographics and treatment plan forms are using `me.hide()` when called).

So to duplicate the issue I:

- Start the program
- Click on a client, program loads all information
- If I click on demographics or treatment plan I can see all information, if I close the form and go back information stays there indefinitely.
- But if I click on any `process.start` pictureboxes and then go into demo or treatment plan, the information is gone.

On the main form, the code to read the file looks like this:

```
        Dim FILE_NAME As String = ""
        Dim TextLine As String
        Dim LineNumber As Integer = -1
        If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then
            Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(FILE_NAME)
            Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
                LineNumber += 1
                TextLine = objReader.ReadLine()
                TextLine.Trim()
                
                ClientInfo(LineNumber) = TextLine 'Saves to list for quick reference later instead of having to reference textboxes
                If LineNumber = 0 Then textbox_FirstName.Text = TextLine
                If LineNumber = 1 Then textbox_LastName.Text = TextLine
                ...
                If LineNumber = 61 Then form_Demographics.textbox_Zip.Text = TextLine

            Loop
            objReader.Close()
        Else
          [irrelevant stuff removed]
        End If
```

Opening Demographics and Treatment plan, respectively:

```
Private Sub PictureBox6_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox6.Click
    form_Demographics.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox7_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox7.Click
    form_TreatmentPlan.Show()
End Sub
```

Closing Treatment Plan and Demographics uses a single `Me.Hide()` line.

Opening a link:

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
    Process.Start("https://www.google.com/search?q=" & form_Demographics.textbox_County.Text & "+" & form_Demographics.textbox_State.Text & "+sheriffs+office+phone+number")
End Sub
```

I know using generic picturebox1 and such names are generally frowned upon but I'm never calling these objects so I just leave them at default, the ones I actually use I try to follow a consistent naming style. :)

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to Stack Overflow! It would help members trying to answer your question if you could include some code samples of the section that isn't working.

Comment: So show us the code that gets run when the PictureBoxes are clicked.  It may help to see the code the opens the other two forms as well.

Comment: Thank you for the responses and sorry there wasn't any code included, not sure what code would have been helpful.  The code may be messy, it's all self-taught so I'm sure there's more efficient ways, I'm open to any suggestions.

Comment: Your code to read the file is changing the fields in the forms.  Where is that code located and how does it get fired?  Does it get run in response to any events?

Comment: Sorry, its a combobox that contains all of the client names, this is the only time the information gets loaded, I dont have any code anywhere that clears the textboxes, clicking on the clients overwrites all information in all the textboxes with the new information.---

`Private Sub ClientBox_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ClientBox.SelectedIndexChanged`

Comment: Does your textfile data actually change during the course of the program?...or would it suffice to run that code ONCE from the main Form's Load() event?

Comment: Cant run from the load event because the combobox can be changed by the user at any time.  The program loads the client data, the user can change any field that needs to be changed, and they save it, which overwrites the file with the new information.

The writing, saving, and loading works fine, its the process.start I think thats deleting the info...on a previous version I had a MenuStrip that did the same thing and it worked fine, it wasn't until I changed it from a MenuStrip to a PictureBox that I started having the issue, I didn't add any code, copied and pasted from menu to picture

Comment: I don't yet see how `Process.Start()` is causing your problem.  You have `Dim FILE_NAME As String = ""`.  How is `FILE_NAME` getting changed to point to a proper file as a result of the ComboBox changing?  You're not presenting the entire process/picture properly.

Comment: I figured it out, and its completely unrelated to process.start...when I made the pictureboxes I went into demographics and treatment plan and changed the formBorderStyle from None to FixedToolWindow for better aesthetics...what was happening was when I X'd out of those forms(out of habit) instead of using the "Back" button I made it was unloading the forms instead of hiding the forms.  I completely forgot I changed the border style.  Sorry for wasting your time, I really appreciate the help though.